# git pull doesn't "download" changed files from origin

Tags: git, git-pull

I am new to git.

I have one repository *[CR]* on Github. This repository, *CR*, is accessed by two different git directories on my local machine - *g01* and *g02*. Both have *CR* as origin. In *g02* I modified two files (*f01* and *f02*), added and committed them and did a git push. The repository *CR* on Github was successfully updated.

Meanwhile, on *g01* these two files (*f01* and *f02*) were modified added and committed.
When trying a git pull on *g01* I expect that the two modified files (*f01* and *f02*) from *CR* will be merged somehow. Instead I get the message: `Already up-to-date`

The files *f01* and *f02* are different on *g01* and *g02*. *g02* accords with *CR* but *g01* doesn't.

What could be the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: Could they be pointed at different braches?

Comment: each local repository has only one branch (master) and is pointing to origin/master

Comment: when you do "git log" in g01, it doesn't contain the commit you pushed from g02?

Comment: Please post the result of `git log -5` on the two repositories.

Comment: OK - could reproduce this. It was my fault. Yesterday I must have been already merged these files. Today looking at the different reps I saw the differences in the files and was surprised that I wasn't been asked to merge these files.